# Custom axis function in D3JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using D3JS and I want an axis in x with this kind of values : 125, 250, 500, 1000 ... until 8000. So multiply by 2 my values each time.

So I tried a Quantize Scales but axis do not support it.

How can I do this ? Can I do a custom mathematical function like y = mx + b (where m = 2 in my case and b = 0) and use it in axis?

Here you can see my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/h2juD/4/)

```
Podelo
```

Comment: Do you want an actual scale that does this or just the axis labels?

Comment: A scale is better because my points in x axis have to follow the same logic

Comment: Then you'll have to implement your own scale.

Comment: How can we do this? There is some examples?

Comment: For example the [linear scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/scale/linear.js).

Comment: ok, but how can I do this? I don't want to edit the source code and if I make another (with a custom linear scale) file I can't access to several properties/methods wich are only in the source code.

Comment: You can use it as a template to implement your own scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [linear scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-linear) is pretty flexible if you mass in multiple values for the range and domain to create a polylinear scale:

```
tickWidth = (ChartWidth - padding)/7
xScale = d3.scale.linear()
           .domain([0, 125, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000])
           .range(d3.range(8).map(function(d){ return d*tickWidth; }));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h2juD/6/

Comment: Thanks so much! I knew there was a trick but I don't control completely d3 functions like range and others.